# Como fazer para comparar dois vetores em java script

Tags: javascript

tenho um trabalho pra fazer sobre um tema sobre matemática dai tenho q fazer sobre conjuntos dai pensei em fazer uma intersecção que seria mostrar apenas os números que se repetem nos dois conjuntos, mas não to conseguindo, consegui apenas coletar os dados e mostrar os conjuntos digitados.

```js
var elemento = [];
var conjuntos = [];

numcon = prompt("Digite o Numero de Conjuntos:", "")
if (numcon == 0) {
  alert("Numero de Conjunto tem que ser maior que zero")
} else {

  for (var i = 1; i <= numcon; i++) {
    numelemt = prompt("digite o numero de elmentos do " + "  " + i + "º" + "  conjuntos:", "")
    conjuntos[i - 1] = [];
    if (numelemt == 0) {
      alert("Este conjunto sera nulo")
    } else {
      for (var cont1 = 1; cont1 <= numelemt; cont1++) {
        elemt = window.prompt("Digite o" + " " + cont1 + "º" + " " + "elemento do conjunto nº" + " " + i);

        conjuntos[i - 1].push(elemt)
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(conjuntos)

for (var cont3 = 0; cont3 < conjuntos.length; cont3++) {
  document.write("<br>" + "conjunto " + (cont3 + 1) + " é {")
  for (var cont4 = 0; cont4 < conjuntos[cont3].length; cont4++) {
    if (cont4 == conjuntos[cont3].length - 1) {
      document.write(conjuntos[cont3][cont4]);
    } else {
      document.write(conjuntos[cont3][cont4] + ",");
    }
    //conjunto 1 é: {552655}
  }
  document.write("}");
}
```

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo desse input que queres comparar?

Comment: por ex vou esta digitando os números de dois conjuntos o primeiro 1,2,3,4, e o segundo 3,4,5,6, dai queria comparar esses dois vetores pra me mostrar os números iguais nos dois , que seria o 3,4

Answer (score 2):

É possível fazer isso de uma maneira bem simples! O `Array` em JavaScript tem um método chamado `filter()` e um método chamado `indexOf()`.

## `filter()`

O `filter()` retorna um array com os elementos que se aplicam a uma condição que você fornece através de uma função.

## `indexOf()`

O `indexOf()` retorna o índice de um elemento no arranjo. Se ele não for encontrado, é retornado `-1`.

## Solução

A solução para o seu problema seria:

```
conjuntos[i-1].filter(valor => -1 !== conjuntos[i].indexOf(valor));
```

Veja o snippet abaixo:

```js
var elemento = [];
var conjuntos = [];

numcon = prompt("Digite o Numero de Conjuntos:", "")
if (numcon == 0) {
  alert("Numero de Conjunto tem que ser maior que zero")
} else {

  for (var i = 1; i <= numcon; i++) {
    numelemt = prompt("digite o numero de elmentos do " + "  " + i + "º" + "  conjuntos:", "")
    conjuntos[i - 1] = [];
    if (numelemt == 0) {
      alert("Este conjunto sera nulo")
    } else {
      for (var cont1 = 1; cont1 <= numelemt; cont1++) {
        elemt = window.prompt("Digite o" + " " + cont1 + "º" + " " + "elemento do conjunto nº" + " " + i);
        conjuntos[i - 1].push(elemt)
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(conjuntos)
for( let i = 1; i < conjuntos.length; i++) {
    const intersecao = conjuntos[i-1].filter(valor => -1 !== conjuntos[i].indexOf(valor));
    console.log(`A interseção entre os conjuntos ${i} e ${i+1} é:`, intersecao);

}
```

Referência da resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1885569/9036322